# Inviting my friend to my minecraft pc singleplayer world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friend uses minecraft pocket edition while I use minecraft pc edition. Is it possible to invite my friend to my singleplayer world? and how?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible, for this one big reason (there are more, but I'm listing this main one)

PC has blocks and items that haven't been added to PE (and vice-versa)